# MAX + FILTER + MIN functions in a conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

When I put the formula `=MAX(FILTER(I2:I,H2:H=MIN(H2:H)))` in cell `M2` and use `=$I1=$M$2` in conditional formatting custom function it paints the entire line perfectly, but when I use the formula inside the conditional formatting custom function like this `=$I1=MAX(FILTER(I2:I,H2:H=MIN(H2:H)))`, nothing is painted.

What do I need to adjust for this to resolve?

Comment: Try `=$I1=MAX(FILTER(I:I,H:H=MIN(H:H)))`. I think you can use `MAXIFS()` instead of `FILTER()` for conditional formatting.

Comment: Hi @Harun24HR ```=$I1=MAXIFS($I:I,$H:H,MIN($H:H))``` putting ```$``` in all column specs worked perfectly. But unfortunately there are values in ```line 1``` so this can interfere with the results, correct? So I think I need to find a way that I can specify it to be from ```line 2```.

Comment: Then try `=$I2=MAX(FILTER(I2:I,H2:H=MIN(H2:H)))` or show us your sample data so that we can suggest better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=$I2=MAX(FILTER($I$2:$I, $H$2:$H=MIN($H$2:$H)))
```